# Session between tabs - apache loadbalancer

Tags: apache, tomcat, load-balancing, session-cookies

I have apache load balancer (header, cookie) and two apache tomcat 
backend servers. It is possible to setup apache to handle session 
between browser tabs? 
in this moment I can log in to my backend through my LB but when I 
try to open this same link in other tab (wihout /myapp in URL) I get backend tomcat hello 
page ( why no my application?) 
How can I achieve session sharing? or at least how can I reconfigure 
my LB or backend to show my webapp in second tab not hello page?

Regards

Comment: This is certainly possible. To see why this isn't working for you we'd need to see your reverse proxy configuration from httpd.conf and server.xml for the backend Tomcats

Comment: this is my revers proxy configuration  
ProxyPass /balancer://mycluster !

ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster/
ProxyPassReverse / balancer://mycluster/
my app should be available without /myapp switch. what should i change?

Answer (score 0):

Research Sticky session. This is from my apache config file.

```
Header add Set-Cookie "ROUTEID=.%{BALANCER_WORKER_ROUTE}e; path=/" env=BALANCER_ROUTE_CHANGED
<Proxy balancer://mycluster>
    BalancerMember http://ip1:8080 route=1
    BalancerMember http://ip2:8080 route=2
    ProxySet stickysession=ROUTEID
</Proxy>

ProxyPass /assets !
ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster/
ProxyPassReverse / balancer://mycluster/
```